# Login notification using Ruby/Rails Devise Gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, authentication, devise, rubygems

I am using the Devise Gem and need to display a message when a user successfully logs in, and a message when a login is unsuccessful. I am using Ruby/Rails. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can modify the sessions_controller

```
class SessionsController < ApplicationController
  def create
    ...
    redirect_to root_path, notice: "Signed in sucessfully"
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok after some searching I found the answer.
In your `application.html.erb` add this:

```
<% flash.each do |name, msg| %>
        <%= content_tag(:div, msg, class: "alert alert-info") %>

<% end %>
```

Comment: Hi, it seems that for me Devise is not showing validation by default.
If I give a wrong password, I do not get a "wrong user/password" notification, nor a notification if I log in correctly. Is there a way to make sure the default validation is on?